# 2009 Chevy Impala, won't start battery is good

Tags: starting, chevrolet, troubleshooting, impala

My Impala won't start (non cranking) had the battery checked its at full charge. What should I check next, the alternator or starter. All lights are working fine, when I turn the key lights dim but no noise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's not going to be the alternator, because it has absolutely nothing to do with the ability of the car to start. Do you hear *any* clicking noises (or perhaps a loud "thunk") when you turn the key to the start position? Do the lights dim at all (dash or otherwise) when you turn the key? Which engine do you you have in the car? Is the security indicator light on the dash flashing at you?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the simple and easy.  Clean the battery terminals and connector clamps.  Light corrosion can cause your problem -conductive under light electrical load but open under heavy load.